# How to get a union of list in a specific column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

First,i read excel file with pandas,then i df.groupby("wire") like this:

```
        wire    pin  app             re_range
W1  0    W1      1   K1                   [1]
    2    W1    2,3   K2                [2, 3]
    1    W1      4   K3                   [4]
    5    W1    7~9   K4             [7, 8, 9]
    4    W1  10,11   T4              [10, 11]
    3    W1  21~25   T3  [21, 22, 23, 24, 25]
W2  6    W2      1   K6                   [1]
W3  7    W3      1   K8                   [1]
W4  8    W4      1   K5                   [1]
W5  9    W5      1   K9                   [1]
W6  10   W6      1   K7                   [1]
W7  11   W7      1  K19                   [1]
```

---

so,how can i get all the re_range's lists in W1 unioned ,like:
[1,2,3,4,7,8,9,10,11,21,22,23,24,25]

I tried using "lambda x" method ,but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Can you show what you tried, and what does you expected output look like?

Comment: Output :[1,2,3,4,7,8,9,10,11,21,22,23,24,25]

Answer (score 1):

Using

```
df.re_range.sum(level=0)
```

Comment: Much thanks。In fact,I try to use "lambda x" method， but your answer is simple & effective.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do it without group bying:

```
w1_df = df[df['wire']=='w1']
ranges = w1_df['re_range']
all_ranges = []
for range in ranges:
    all_ranges.extend(range)
```

Comment: The table showed above is just a sample.In fact，there's lot's of wire .And every group should be dealt with like "W1"